How much impact force do I need to break through a one inch thick sheet of diamond?
If I were to try to break through a one inch thick sheet of diamond, how much impact force would it take in joules or newtons?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can't tell this by only this much information.

See section titled "toughness" in this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_properties_of_diamond#:~:text=A%20diamond%20will%20shatter%20if,compared%20to%20most%20engineering%20materials.

This depends on what angle you hit it at, for how long, over what area you apply the force, the relative angle of the crystals in the diamond, the temperature of the diamond, what other strains and stresses the diamond is being subjected to, what is being used to support the diamond against applied forces if anything at all, the atmospheric composition and pressure if any exists, and how willing you are to break a one-inch thick sheet of diamond that’s probably worth more than my house. You’ll need to be more specific.

DO you have a 1" diamond sheet?

Let's a bit simplify a task. Say you want to crush $1~in^3$ of diamond. For that you will need a force that will overcome diamond tensile strength,
$$ F = \sigma A ,$$
Diamond tensile strength is about $2.8~GPa$, and cross-section of this small cube will be of course $1~in^2$.
Hence, you need to put an equivalent of $(2.8 GPa × 1~in^2)/g \approx 180~\text{metric tonnes}$ of mass on top of this diamond cube to crush it (about the mass of an average blue whale).
